# Get user type in custom submit_line.html template

Tags: python, django

I added a submit button in submit_line.html. I want to show it just for staff users and not for superusers.
I have the following template stub:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %} 
  submit-button
{% else %}
  no submit-button
{% endif %}
```

But any user I access the page with gets the submit-button code

I also verified that context processor is enabled in "settings.py" as we can read in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates.

It seems that the django variable user is outside this scope. 
How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: No errors, but for each type of users (superusers, staff...) my custom button is shown. 
I tried to print the user logged in through {{user}} but I get an empty string.

Comment: Please show the template code relevant to your question

Comment: {% load i18n admin_urls %}
<div> 
 {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                          ...show default buttons
        {%else%}
                            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Send Email' %}" name="_send_email" />
{%endif%}

</div>

Answer (score 0):

Right now it works!!
In the admin template submit_line.html is passed context information through `takes_context=True` in the inclusion tag submit_row inside the admin_modify.py file. To have the information of the user is necessary to pass the request as well:

```
admin_modify.py 


from django.contrib import admin


@register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_row(context, request):
"""
Displays the row of buttons for delete and save. I added the user variable to the context
and I pass it in ctx.
"""
opts = context['opts']
change = context['change']
is_popup = context['is_popup']
save_as = context['save_as']
user = request.user
ctx = {
    'user_type': user,
    'opts': opts,
    'show_delete_link': (
     ..........
```

I added the request parameter in change_form.html when submit_row inclusion tag is called:

```
change_form.html

{% submit_row request %}
```

Finally, in submit_line.html I can use:

```
submit_line.html

{% if user_type.is_superuser %}
```